# How to use and OR inside an AND operator for a where clause

Tags: sql, vertica

I would like my WHERE clause to evaluate the AND and the OR inside of an AND.

```
 SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM date_hired dh WHERE id = e.id
                                AND (
                                        (dh.datehired <= e.interview_start_date)
                                        OR 
                                        (dh.datehired BETWEEN e.interview_start_date AND e.last_job_date)
                                    )
                    AND dh.office = 'Med-office'
                    )
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS decision
FROM new_table n
JOIN old_table e ON e.id=n.id
```

Comment: Do you see the WHERE clause in the SELECT * FROM date_hired? the OR statement inside that subquery is not working

Comment: Fair enough, I read too fast. Still, what is your question? "is not working" doesn't mean anything

Comment: Yes! This is the error i am getting "correlated subquery expressions under OR not supported"

Comment: What about that error message is unclear to you?

Comment: How can I fix the OR statement in the query above

Comment: Wonder if between doesn't work with exists...   break it into a >= and <=.

Comment: the OR inside an EXISTS is not supported in VERTICA

Answer (score 0):

Vertica is a mass data database, and it prefers more efficient joins and existence checks than correlated sub-selects - what an `EXISTS` predicate boils down to - and what results in a slowing-down nested loop.

Put the `datehired` check into a `LEFT JOIN` predicate with a Common Table Expression - in a `WITH` clause. If the joined table's columns are NULL, the matching `id` does not exist, so finally just check for being NULL.

```
WITH
dh AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , datehired
  FROM date_hired
  WHERE dh.office = 'Med-office'
) 
SELECT
  id
, nam 
, CASE WHEN dh.id IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS decision
FROM new_table n
JOIN old_table e USING(id)
LEFT JOIN dh 
  ON e.id = = dh.id
 AND (
   dh.datehired <= e.interview_start_date
  OR 
   dh.datehired BETWEEN e.interview_start_date AND e.last_job_date
 )
```